# .htaccess for pagination to redirect example.com/page/page_id

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

htaccess code to redirect page without have to call extension. i'm trying to implement pagination without using ?page=2 or ?page=3 instead i try to use example.com/page/2 etc with uri.

for example i have example.com/page/2 , i would like to redirect it to page.php

but i also want to be able to call all of the file without php extension

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

it works but when i try to call example.com/page/2 it says Object not found!

here is my page.php

```
<?php 
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uri_array = explode("/", $uri);
echo $uri_array[3];
```

im trying to get the value from page_id for my pagination

Comment: do you mean Page not found?

Comment: no it says object not found

Comment: where does it say "object not found"? In the browser, or in your apache logs? seems to me that the page is loaded and you have a PHP error ?

Comment: Then edit your question to show your php code and the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see that you're in a wrong way as you make your own page.php for simply doing it for example.com/page/2 instead you should do this in your index.php example.com/index.php?page=page_id so you will be able to rewrite it as example.com/page/page_id

it's common mistake for someone who new to pagination to create somethings like that